# Best package to profile R code

Tags: ide, r, profiling

I need to profile R code, preferably with a graphical interface. Which package + IDE would be the best for this task? I didn't know there would be different kinds of profiling in R (when I profile in other languages, I get all I need in the same interface), but my requirements are, in order of importance:

1. Understand which are the functions where my code spends more time. Ideally, frequency of call would be also needed, not just total time (it makes an hell of a difference if function A is taking an hour of CPU time because it's being called one million times, or 10 times but each call takes 6 minutes);
2. Be able to drill down at line level and see which lines take more time in a single function call;
3. Finally, less important but nice to have, understand the memory footprint of the functions

PS concerning the IDE, I guess you people will suggest me to use RStudio and that's perfectly fine, but I didn't want to hardwire the IDE choice, because I really need to do profiling well, and if that requires me to change IDE, I'm willing to pay that price.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's some useful information at SO:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7252602/digging-into-r-profiling-information

In the old days, it was common to use Rprof, and you can see `?Rprof` for more information, but clearly you want something more user friendly.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6262203/measuring-function-execution-time-in-r

If you look at the list of packages you see several whose name suggest the possibility of a constructed interface: profileR, profilr, profr, profvis.

The [`profvis`- package](https://rstudio.github.io/profvis/) appears to be a successor to the `profr`-package, since it seems to be supported by Rstudio and `profr` (by Hadley) hasn't been updated recently. So trying profvis (possibly inside Rstudio but it should work in other IDEs)  would probably be the immediate choice to try.

[This article appeared relative relatively recently](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Ruizhu_Huang/publication/325108286_A_Case_Study_of_R_Performance_Analysis_and_Optimization/links/5afca968458515e9a59afafa/A-Case-Study-of-R-Performance-Analysis-and-Optimization.pdf?origin=publication_list) and has a useful list of packages and comparisons. The comparison of feature set suggest that profvis may be the most complete strategy.

Comment: when I saw your avatar I said "no way! That reputation score can't be right! What, did he give all of his reputation away in countless bounties? Does reputation get reset after you exceed a certain score?!". Then I realized this is Software Recommendations ;-P

Comment: I have been fairly generous with the few bounties I’ve offered but I’ve had the same sort of whiplash experience going to MetaSO where my opinions are not typically well-received and I get little cared for my “years of service”.